# how innodb lock secondary index when update

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

When I study to UPDATE a secondary index record, specified by primary key, the secondary index X lock cannot be shown by using `show engine innodb status`. However, when I attempt to lock this secondary index record in another session，it appeared.

> When UPDATE modifies a clustered index record, implicit locks are taken on affected secondary index records. The UPDATE operation also takes shared locks on affected secondary index records when performing duplicate check scans prior to inserting new secondary index records, and when inserting new secondary index records. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

## table info

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_lock` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `keyf` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `uniqf` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `nokeyf` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_b` (`uniqf`),
  KEY `idx_a` (`keyf`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## TEST 1

```sql
begin;
update test_lock set keyf=3 where id = 3;
show engine innodb status;
```

### transaction info

only IX and PRIMARY INDEX X locks can be seen.

```
---TRANSACTION 14987, ACTIVE 5 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 758, OS thread handle 139959492560640, query id 82046 localhost root
TABLE LOCK table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14987 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14987 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 8 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000003a8b; asc     : ;;
 2: len 7; hex 26000001e12bbe; asc &    + ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8000000d; asc     ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
```

## TEST 2

lock the secondary record in annother session.

1. session 1

```sql
begin;
update test_lock set keyf=3 where id = 3;
```

2. session 2

```sql
begin;
select * from test_lock where keyf = 3 for update;
```

3. `show engine innodb status;`  we can see that X LOCK for idx_a appeared. I wonder why, thanks.

```
---TRANSACTION 14992, ACTIVE 20 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 756, OS thread handle 139959487694592, query id 82052 localhost root Sending data
select * from test_lock where keyf = 3 for update
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 14992, sees < 14987
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 5 n bits 80 index idx_a of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14992 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

------------------
TABLE LOCK table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14992 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 5 n bits 80 index idx_a of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14992 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14992 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000000039f7; asc     9 ;;
 2: len 7; hex 26000001e12ae3; asc &    * ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 5 n bits 80 index idx_a of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14992 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

---TRANSACTION 14987, ACTIVE 394 sec
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 758, OS thread handle 139959492560640, query id 82046 localhost root
TABLE LOCK table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14987 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14987 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 8 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000003a8b; asc     : ;;
 2: len 7; hex 26000001e12bbe; asc &    + ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8000000d; asc     ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

RECORD LOCKS space id 64 page no 5 n bits 80 index idx_a of table `study`.`test_lock` trx id 14987 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
```

Comment: it is related to implicit lock http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/mysql-locking